# python : understaning partial functions

Tags: python

I am trying to get my head around this snippet :

```
def a_func(a, b, c):
  print "a: %s\nb: %s\nc: %s" %(a, b, c)

def partial(fn, *args):
  print "Args in partial : %s" %str(args)      
  def fn_part(*fn_args):
    print "fn_args in fn_part : %s" %fn_args
    return fn(*args+fn_args)    
  return fn_part

print_fn = partial(a_func, 'A', 'B')    
print_fn('C')
```

The output is :

```
Args in partial : ('A', 'B')
fn_args in fn_part : C
a: A
b: B
c: C
```

**How does the control flow here ?**

The function object `print_fn` points to `fn_part`, but also has some variables predefined (`a` and `b`). How can I view variables are already defined for the function ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. `*args` is the tuple of already defined values to pass into `fn()` when `fn_part()` is called. You *already* print this.

Comment: `a_func` needs three variables defined. We already defined `a` and `b`. What if say I wished to change them ? `print_fn('a2, 'b2', 'c')` gives an error.

Comment: You can't, not with this setup; the `args` closure cannot be replaced.

Comment: I was hoping for some remarks on the issue as an answer. Maybe workarounds etc.

Comment: You can create objects that can be called like functions (actually, functions in Python *are* objects, but let's leave this aside for now). Inside such an object, you can store the bound parameters and also modify them.

Comment: Can you illustrate this with code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fn_part()` function accesses `args` as a *closure*. You could read those from the returned function object:

```
>>> print_fn = partial(a_func, 'A', 'B')    
Args in partial : ('A', 'B')
>>> print_fn.__closure__
(<cell at 0x102a90be8: tuple object at 0x10075bf38>, <cell at 0x102a901d8: function object at 0x102aa1848>)
>>> print_fn.__closure__[0].cell_contents
('A', 'B')
```

You cannot alter the closure; you'd create a *new* `partial()` object instead, or just call the original function directly.